# How can I use references in YAML?

Tags: python, yaml

I have this YAML:

```
app_name: my_app
version:
  1.0:
    path: /my_app/1.0
  2.0:
    path: /my_app/2.0
```

Is it possible to somehow avoid typing out "my_app" and its version and instead read that from the YAML itself by using some sort of referencing?

I had something like this in mind:

```
app_name: my_app
version:
  1.0:
    path: /@app_name/$key[-1]
  2.0:
    path: /@app_name/$key[-1]
```

In the end, I intend to read this into a Python dictionary.

Comment: There seems to be no need to do `@1.0`, assuming `@key[-1]` means take the key associated with this value one level up. (if @key[0] would mean `path`)

Comment: Yes, I changed my pseudo code a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mechanism in YAML that does substitution on substrings of scalars, the best you have are anchors and aliases, and they refer to whole scalars or collections (mappings, sequences).

If you want to do such thing you will have to do the substitution after parsing in the YAML, interpreting the various values and rebuilding the data structure.

There are several examples (including here on [so]) of substitution where some part of the YAML is used as dictionary to replace other parts. When you do that you can parse the YAML input once, substitute on the source, and reparse the output of that substitution. 
Because you use relative references, that will not work for you and you would need to do the substitution in the parsed tree.
The alternative is modifying the parser to strip the `@` from inputs and do this on the fly.

In both cases it would be a bad idea to use the same token (`@`) for marking a key to "store" its value (`@app_name`), as well as marking a key to store the key itself (`@1.0`), and for using the associated value (which you do in two completely different ways `@app_name` and `@key[-1]`).

Comment: Thanks. I might go with [PyYAML aliases](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Aliases) or [jsonref](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonref) for this one (meaning using JSON instead of YAML), although I'd have to do some parsing and substitution myself in order to fetch the version numbers. I changed my pseudo code as I agree with your comment of how I used `@` in it.

Comment: The thing I forgot to mention is that `@` is a reserved letter and a scalar starting with it needs to be quoted. Using `$` to introduce a function (`key` that takes a parameter) seems more natural somehow. If you are going to (also) hack the parser then please have a look at [`ruamel.yaml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/) (disclaimer: I am the author), which has many things advantages over PyYAML, including supporting YAML 1.2 and being maintained.